# Selenium C# Interact with Chrome Microphone Window

Tags: c#, selenium, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have an application that when initiated, I receive the popup that "https://example.com wants to:"
"Use your microphone"

I have looked at autoit but it has not been helping. I was trying to use an x/y coordinate but no luck.  The autoit window info gives me a name and a class but button info is not there.

Anyone have a way around this issue?

Comment: You can use TestStack.White to handle windows applications. Can you give me the URL of your web site so I can show you an example code?

Comment: it is all proprietary so I can't get you access.  This all stems around Chrome_WidgetWin_1. I am starting to find other posts but no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly:

```
$WinTitle = "[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]"
WinWait($WinTitle)
WinActivate($WinTitle)
ControlSend($WinTitle, "", "", "{TAB}{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got around it using AutoIT. Remove one of the Send("+{TAB}") to set it to Block. I tried removing both of these and just using the enter for Allow but it did not work.

```
Allow Microphone for Chrome:
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Outfile=chromeClickAllow.exe
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
Sleep(2000)
WinActivate("Tabs Outliner")
WinWait("[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]")
Sleep(500)
WinActivate("[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]")
Send("+{TAB}")
Send("+{TAB}")
Send("{ENTER}")
```